# Setting scalacOptions for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-scala

I have a sbt project which I have imported into IntelliJ IDEA. This project includes the [splain](https://github.com/tek/splain) compiler plugin which includes colour codes in some compiler messages.

When compiling in IntelliJ IDEA then these colour codes are not interpreted. I can add `"-P:splain:color:false"` to the **Additional compiler options** in **Preferences** which works but is lost when I refresh the sbt project.

Is there a way to set the `scalacOptions` in sbt so that it only applies to IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IntelliJ Scala plugin sets the `-Didea.managed=true` system property when starting sbt instances, so this could work:

```
scalacOptions += if (System.getProperty("idea.managed") == "true") {
  "-P:splain:color:false"
} else {
  "-P:splain:color:true"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this particular problem with colour output and splain but it is not a general solution for setting `scalacOptions` that only apply to IntelliJ IDEA.

```
scalacOptions += if (ConsoleAppender.formatEnabledInEnv) {
  "-P:splain:color:true"
} else {
  "-P:splain:color:false"
}
```

I already run sbt with `-no-colors` during the build so having the compiler option dependent on this made sense. It was a bit of an educated guess that this would also solve the problem in IntelliJ IDEA.